# testthat expect_identical FALSE until wrapped in as.data.table

Tags: r, testthat

I have read up on the differences between expect_equal and expect_identical.

That being said, I have a function which produces a data table that looks like:

```
       Thing1 Thing2 Thing3
Thing1   34.6   23.4   54.2
Thing2   34.7   33.2   32.1
Thing3   32.7   33.5   33.8

 structure(list(` ` = c("Thing1", "Thing2", "Thing3"), `Thing1` = c(34.6,
 34.7, 32.7), `Thing2` = c(32.4, 33.2, 33.5), `Thing3` = c(33,
 32.1, 33.8)), .Names = c(" ", "Thing1", "Thing2", "Thing3"), row.names = c(NA,
 -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Let's call this table `output`. I save this data.table in a .rds, then reload it with readRDS. This new table is called `test`. The structure is unchanged, and only the pointers differ. Despite this, running `identical(test, output)` yields false. Again, the structures are identical expect for the pointer. All classes are the same.

However, this: `identical(as.data.table(test), output)` yields `TRUE`. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? It's not a simple class issue. I'm at a loss.

You can recreate this issue yourself by doing something like:

```
x <- as.data.table(mtcars)
saveRDS(x, "~/test.rds")
y <- readRDS("~/test.rds")
str(x)
str(y)
identical(x, y)
```

**UPDATE**

I checked `mem_change()` on both objects, and it is different. However, `object.size()` is the same.

Comment: Check with `all.equal`

Comment: `all.equal(test, output)` yields `TRUE`

Comment: @akrun I'm really more interested in ***why*** this is happening